# Elasticsearch 7.17.5 index template unknown setting issue

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 7.17.5 and trying to create an index template.
But I am getting the following error and couldn't figure out what is wrong.

`Caused by: co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/indices.put_index_template] failed: [invalid_index_template_exception] index_template [my-index-template] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: unknown setting [index.mappings.total_fields.limit] did you mean any of [index.mapping.total_fields.limit, index.mapping.nested_fields.limit, index.mapping.dimension_fields.limit]?;]`

And this is my index template:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "index_patterns": [
        "my-index-template",
        "my-index-template-*"
    ],
    "template": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": 3,
                "number_of_replicas": 2,
                "max_ngram_diff": 7,
                "mappings": {
                    "total_fields": {
                        "limit": 1000
                    }
                }
            },
            "analysis": {
                ...
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the provided options in the error message, but still no success.

And when I try "mapping" without 's' based on the [elasticsearch reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html#mapping-settings-limit), I get the following error:

`Caused by: co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.IndexSettings: Unknown field 'mapping' (JSON path: template.settings.index.mapping) (line no=13, column no=26, offset=326)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using mapping(s) with `s` while actually setting is without `s`, so you can fix use by changing it to mapping.

Refer setting name https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html#mapping-settings-limit

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "index_patterns": [
        "my-index-template",
        "my-index-template-*"
    ],
    "template": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": 3,
                "number_of_replicas": 2,
                "max_ngram_diff": 7,
                "mapping": { // Note this
                    "total_fields": {
                        "limit": 1000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this works fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Amit, I had tried that too. Gives me 'unknown field' error. I updated descriptions of the question as well.

Comment: @Saeed you must be doing something wrong, I tried and it worked for me, can you provide your complete template so that i can try creating it

Comment: @Saeed are you still facing issue? if so, as mentioned in previous comment please provide complete template

Comment: @Saeed it been some time, would be great if you can update if you are able to solve the issue or not

Comment: Hi @Amit, I tried the above template. It gives me the following error. I have removed all the other configs from the index template as well.

Caused by: co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.indices.IndexSettings: Unknown field 'mapping' (JSON path: template.settings.index.mapping) (line no=13, column no=26, offset=327)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

This is a bug in java api 7.17.5. They have fixed it in 7.17.6+ and should be "mapping" instead of "mappings".